# How to set route node properties?

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

While monitoring an Apache Camel application with hawt.io, I noticed that the nodes of a camel route have some properties that I cannot influence with the Java DSL, but which are displayed in hawt.io. It would be pretty awesome if you could define them anyway.

I am particularly interested in the id and the description of a node in the route. My route currently looks something like this (screenshot below):

- My route

  - rabbitmq://tso11
  - log4
  - process4
  - to3
  - process5
  - to4

The displayed names (log4, process4, process5, ...) are automatically generated "id" properties. There is also an always empty property "description".

It would be awesome if I could change this somehow for a much better readable route:

- My route

  - rabbitmq://tso11
  - log incoming message
  - process for header extraction
  - to xslt processor additional-mappint.xslt
  - process for conversion to nms42 format
  - to nms42 endpoint

Maybe there is a way? Maybe only with XML based DSL?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java DSL, you can set the id of a node thanks to the method [`id(String id)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-core-model/3.15.0/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.html#id(java.lang.String)).

In the next example, the id of the endpoint `mock:bar` has been set to `bar`:

```
from("direct:start")
  .to("mock:foo")
  .to("mock:bar").id("bar")
  .to("mock:result");
```

Comment: Thax. I will try and reply afterwards. 
By the way: Good point to change the title of this post!

Comment: Yeah, it’s better to go straight to the point

Comment: Works!

Is there any documentation that I missed? Or any detailed tutorial about route building besides component API?

And I'd like to have a "name" in addition to the "id" of a route node which must not be unqiue accross all routes in the same context...

But the id helps alot. Thanx!

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific documentation about that. Setting id to a node is quite common when we need to ["weave" a route](https://camel.apache.org/manual/advice-with.html#_weave_using_node_selection) for testing purpose. Regarding the name, AFAIK there is no way to set a name to a node.